# Change pitch of audio buffer

Tags: audio, signal-processing, web-audio-api, pitch-shifting

I am trying to change the pitch of a buffer sample using a [scriptprocessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode), but what kind of formulas do I need to do this? <strike>I am not looking for the exact js code, but just for some general mathematical how to.</strike> I would love to have some code for this, as the first answer has a lot of formulas where I have no idea on how to implement that in JS.

I know that this is working with time, but according to [this](http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/time-pitch-overview/) it can be done with the FFT, but I have no idea how one should do that.

Answer (score 0):

For one method of doing time-pitch modification using an FFT, look up [phase vocoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_vocoder).  Here's one explanation of how a phase vocoder works (but a search will turn up many others): http://www.guitarpitchshifter.com/algorithm.html

Comment: This document looks interesting, although I only understand half of it. I think I'd better change my question, that some javascript code will be handy as I have no idea how I would implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe  https://github.com/mikolalysenko/pitch-shift would be appropriate (the quality is not on par with other code, but this library is rather easy to understand/use). You can hear a demo at http://mikolalysenko.github.io/pitch-shift/.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! Thanks. As the idea was to learn from this, I will try to find out how it works.